# Should I deploy ./assets/js/*.js and ./assets/css/*.css in a laravel project

Tags: node.js, laravel, continuous-integration, vite, laravel-10

In my continious integration pipeline I run the following commands:

```
# install php dependencies
composer install

# Build Frontend
npm install
npm run build

# Run unit tests - STOP PIPELINE IF FAILS
./vendor/bin/phpunit

# Remove dependencies used only for dev
composer install --no-dev

# Make a .env file for production somehow
```

And at this step:

```
npm install
npm run build
```

A noticed that upon `public/build/assets` all the nessesary js and Css files are generated. In my project I load them at view level as:

```
@vite(['resources/js/main.js'])
```

And my `vite.config.js` is:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import inject from "@rollup/plugin-inject";

import { readdirSync,lstatSync } from 'fs';
import { resolve } from 'path';


function getFilesFromDir(dir) {
    const filesToReturn = [];

    function walkDir(currentPath) {

        if(lstatSync(currentPath).isFile()){
            filesToReturn.push(currentPath);
            return;
        }

        const files = readdirSync(currentPath);
        for (let i in files) {
            console.log(files[i]);
            const curFile = resolve(currentPath, files[i]);
            if(lstatSync(curFile).isDirectory()){
                walkDir(curFile);
                continue;
            }
            const file = resolve(dir, files[i]);
            filesToReturn.push(file);
        }
    }

    walkDir(resolve(__dirname, dir));
    return filesToReturn;
}


// Get all .css and .scss files in the directory
const pageStyles = getFilesFromDir('./resources/css');
const js = getFilesFromDir('./resources/js');
const img = getFilesFromDir('./resources/images');

const paths = [

    ...pageStyles,
    ...js,

    'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
    'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js',
    'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
]

console.log(paths);

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input:paths,
            refresh: true,
        }),
        inject({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
        }),
    ],
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            external: [
                "js/modules/*",
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see the js and css modues are in:

- `assets/js/`
- `assets/css`
  Respectively.

Therefore, I wonder, because all frontend assets are build via vite in my pipeline. The built assets are built assets are located upon `./public/build/assets`.

Is there any use of `./resources/js` and `./resources/css` once my app has been built. Or once frontend assets are build there's no use for these folders upon production?

Also I wonder if there's a need to `vite.config.js` as well once all frontend assets have been built in the production.